# access a text field by php

Tags: theming, 7

I created a text field in my "content type". as I do with php to access this value?
I would print it in a similar way:

```
 <?php print $submitted; ?>
```

in node.tpl.php and prevent it from being printed in an automatic way.

EDIT

I put this command in the file node.tpl.php:

```
<?php print $field_nazionalita_1; ?>
```

the result is:

```
Array([und] => Array(
   [0] => Array(
      [value] => francia 
      [format] => 
      [safe_value] => francia
   ) 
  ) 
)
```

the result that I want is:
francia

but only if I inserted a value in the field.

I know little php, you can help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read about the [`field_view_field()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_view_field/7), something like this should work for you:

```
print render(field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_nazionalita_1'));
```

Comment: thanks, There is way to don't make appear the key but only value?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, can you try to be a little more specific?

Answer (score 0):

Depends what your field is called, but you can get it directly from any node object created by node_load().

Do something like this and you'll see the structure of your node object which your field will be in:

```
<?php
  print_r($node);
?>
```

Comment: can I only put so? $ + name_variable?

Comment: mmm, that's how php works. How much php experience do you have?

Comment: I know little php, you can help me? you see above...

Comment: yes... `<?php print $field_nazionalita_1['und'][0]['value'] ?>`